# Trackpad secondary click requires more pressure than usual in Mojave beta

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, beta, mojave

I've just updated my MacBook Pro Retina Early 2015 to Mojave via Apple Beta Software Program.

Everything works smoothly except the Trackpad.

*Tap with one* or *tap with two or three fingers* work as usual, but *click with two fingers* became extremely hard. I need to push my two fingers with more than usual pressure to make it work.

My trackpad settings are shown below.

How can I make *click with two fingers* as soft as before? Thanks.

Version: 10.14 Beta (18A314k)

[image]

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.

Comment: FWIW I have exactly the same issue, so I assume it's a bug?

Comment: Same problem here. Macbook Air Mid-2012. Secondary click tapping two fingers doesnt work anymore. I need to press the touchpad (and hear a mechanical click) to work.

Comment: Im having the same issues. Do you still experience them?

Comment: I have the same problem in the stable built.

Comment: I've got the same problem in the released version of 10.14.2

Comment: @Benj Thanks for returning to a question from almost a year ago to add your comment.  I don’t know what you’re talking about in regard to ‘opinion-based’.  My link is to a meta post that indicates what info should be in a question when beta software is involved and was months prior to the comments that followed. Please explain what you think I should’ve done differently.

Comment: @Benj Ok, thanks.  Going forward, it would be best if you simply avoid commenting on very old posts to add information that’s neither timely nor informative.  Comments are meant to clarify questions and not for irrelevant comments or opinion.

Comment: @fsb of course, I understand. Perhaps also you could clean up your comments when they are outdated.

Comment: I'm experiencing this on my 2018 13" MacBook Pro running 10.14.6, I'm *sure* it didn't used to be this hard to right-click. It's 2x stiffer than when left-clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would solve the issue but you could try and pass by the Apple store or certified repair center and see if they could help you recalibrate the trackpad.

Service centers have tools to calibrate trackpads. I've been an Apple Certified Mac Technician for 6 years and we do this every time a machine has been opened.